# Sort by sub category using a union

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by, union

Right now I'm sorting by 4 categories and displaying them. The first category, agriculture, needs to have tractors sorted at the top first and then the rest of the agriculture equipment.  Tractors have the categoryid of 1108, 1109, 1110, 1111.

This is the query that is being used now:

```
SELECT category, manufacturer, model, serialnumber, stocknumber, owningbusinessunit, statecode, picturessortorder, yeartext, agriculturalequipmentid, listprice, locationidname, hours, detaileddescription, briefdescription
FROM AgriculturalEquipment 
ORDER BY category, manufacturer, model DESC, yeartext DESC
```

This is what I have so far to display the tractors first in the ag category:

```
SELECT TOP 100000 category, categoryid, manufacturer, model, serialnumber, stocknumber, owningbusinessunit, statecode, picturessortorder, yeartext, agriculturalequipmentid, listprice, locationidname, hours, detaileddescription, briefdescription FROM agriculturalequipment WHERE categoryid IN
(SELECT CategoryID FROM (
SELECT top 100000 CategoryID
FROM AgriculturalEquipment AS AgriculturalEquipment
Where CategoryID in ('1108','1109','1110','1111')
ORDER BY categoryid, manufacturer, model DESC, yeartext DESC) A Group by a.categoryid) 

UNION

SELECT TOP 100000 category, categoryid, manufacturer, model, serialnumber, stocknumber, owningbusinessunit, statecode, picturessortorder, yeartext, sads_agriculturalequipmentid, listprice, locationidname, hours, detaileddescription, briefdescription FROM agriculturalequipment WHEREcategoryid IN
(SELECT CategoryID FROM(
SELECT top 100000 CategoryID
FROM AgriculturalEquipment AS AgriculturalEquipment 
WHERE CategoryID not in ('1108','1109','1110','1111')
ORDER BY category, manufacturer, model DESC, yeartext DESC) B GROUP BY categoryid)
```

Here are the results I am getting. category should be sorted and go from 1108 to 1111. What am I doing wrong here?

```
  Category                     catid   manufact

Tractors - 100 HP to 174 HP     1109    AGRI-POWER
Tractors - 100 HP to 174 HP     1109    CASE IH
Tractors - 100 HP to 174 HP     1109    JOHN DEERE
Tractors - 100 HP to 174 HP     1109    NEW HOLLAND
Tractors - 175 HP Or Greater    1108    AGCO ALLIS
Tractors - 175 HP Or Greater    1108    JOHN DEERE
Tractors - Less than 40 HP      1111    AGTRAXX
Tractors - Less than 40 HP      1111    FORDSON
Tractors - 100 HP to 174 HP     1109    INTERNATIONAL
Tractors - 100 HP to 174 HP     1109    JOHN DEERE
Tractors - 100 HP to 174 HP     1109    NEW HOLLAND
Tractors - 175 HP Or Greater    1108    BELL
Tractors - 175 HP Or Greater    1108    DEUTZ
Tractors - 40 HP to 99 HP       1110    AGRI TRACTOR
Tractors - Less than 40 HP      1111    AGTRAXX
Tractors - Less than 40 HP      1111    ALLMAND BROS
Tractors - 100 HP to 174 HP     1109    AGCO WHITE
Tractors - 100 HP to 174 HP     1109    NEW HOLLAND
Tractors - 100 HP to 174 HP     1109    NEW HOLLAND
Tractors - 100 HP to 174 HP     1109    NEW HOLLAND
Tractors - 175 HP Or Greater    1108    WHITE
Tractors - 40 HP to 99 HP       1110    AGRI TRACTOR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of many approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM AgriculturalEquipment 
ORDER BY 
CASE 
  WHEN CategoryID in ('1108','1109','1110','1111') THEN CategoryID
  ELSE CategoryID + 2000 -- 'penalize' other categories
END,
category, manufacturer, model DESC, yeartext DESC
```

Comment: Will you please explain this answer?

Comment: If row value of CategoryID is not in list ('1108','1109','1110','1111') then add to it 2000 to ensure the row will be always below

Comment: SELECT TOP 100000 *
FROM    AgriculturalEquipment
ORDER BY CASE WHEN sads_categoryid IN ('1108', '1109', '1110', '1111') THEN 1
              ELSE 2
         END,categoryid, manufacturer,model

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CategoryID` as the first column in your `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT category, manufacturer, model, serialnumber, stocknumber, owningbusinessunit, statecode, picturessortorder, yeartext, agriculturalequipmentid, listprice, locationidname, hours, detaileddescription, briefdescription
FROM AgriculturalEquipment 
ORDER BY CategoryID, category, manufacturer, model DESC, yeartext DESC
```